# Why is my discord bot sending multiple messages at once?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

U have a conditional statement that if the hour and minute hits a specific time then it start pinging the roles. the first if statement works perfectly, however the 2nd and third if statement, it just keeps on sending multiple messages at once

```
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('reminder functions are working')
        while True:
            cst = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Central')).time()
            if cst.hour == 8 and cst.minute == 59:
                channel = self.client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
                await asyncio.sleep(75)
                await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
                await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
                await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
            elif cst.hour == 12 and cst.minute == 59:
                channel = self.client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
                await asyncio.sleep(75)
                await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
                await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
                await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
            if cst.hour == 17 and cst.minute == 59:
                channel = self.client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
                await asyncio.sleep(75)
                await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
                await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
                await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You check that the time is a precise hour and a precise minute. This means the condition will be true for the whole minute, so your bot will spam until the next minute arrive.

You should add in all the if a condition to check that the second is 0. Be careful tho, as if your loop has a period of more than 1 second, you might skip the exact time when the clock hits the required hour and second. You should rethink how you implementend it

Here is what your code would become

```
async def on_ready(self):
    print('reminder functions are working')
    while True:
        cst = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Central')).time()
        if cst.hour == 8 and cst.minute == 59 and cst.second == 0:
            channel = self.client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await asyncio.sleep(75)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
        elif cst.hour == 12 and cst.minute == 59 and cst.second == 0:
            channel = self.client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await asyncio.sleep(75)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
        if cst.hour == 17 and cst.minute == 59 and cst.second == 0:
            channel = self.client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await asyncio.sleep(75)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
```

Also you should be careful and wait a little bit between each message sent so that your bot isn't considered to be spamming. Or you could send one message that contains all the mentions as well